# Designing the relationship between models where the child model attributes vary based on the "type" of its parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, inheritance, activerecord, database-design

How should I go about designing a relationship between models when the child model's attributes will vary based on the parent type that it belongs to?

For example: Player has_many :projections where the fields on an instance of Projection will vary depending on the "type" of Player that it belongs to.

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :position, :team
  has_many :projections
  validates_uniqueness_of :name, :scope => [:position, :team]
end

class Projection < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :ppr, :salary, :score, :week, :player_id
  belongs_to :player
  validates_uniqueness_of :ppr, :scope => [:week, :player_id]
end
```

So, I want to modify this and add extra attributes/fields to Projection where the fields are different depending on the "position" attribute of the Player model

Examples of the new fields to be added are:

```
:passing, :completions, :receptions, :targets
```

A projection for a Player with position of "QB" will look something like this:

```
Projection.create(passing: 300, completions: 30, week: 8, player_id: 1)
```

While the projection for a Player with position "WR" would look something like this:

```
Projection.create(receptions: 5, targets: 9, week: 8, player_id: 2)
```

**Player with id 1 is of position type "QB" while Player with id 2 is of position type "WR"**

They are both still "Projections" except they will hold different types of data based on the position of the player. My current schema does not account for the players position. Currently, they all share the same attributes. What is the correct way of modifying the existing schema to account for these new data points? I'm worried I might break existing code when modifying to add this new feature.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to give a definite answer without knowing more about your application and use cases.

But from what you describe I'd advise you to just add four new columns to your `projections` table (namely `passing`, `completions`, `receptions` and `targets`). Then fill and read them as needed depending on the Player's position, while some values can stay `NULL`.

If you need custom behaviour (like validations) for different player's projections, then introducing types of projections might help (i.e. single-table inheritance). Remembering the player's position on the projection in one form or another might be a good idea anyway just in case the player changes their position at some point. But maybe you don't need that because you can just display the columns that actually contain values for a given projection.

Hope that helps!